# Push уведомления о минусах и плюсах

Tags: предложение, мобильное-приложение

Обожая приложение Stack Exchange на iPhone, это классно когда сразу видишь комментарии, ответы на твои вопросы и действия. Только вот было бы классно если бы приходило уведомление например: "Голос за вопрос "Как сделать что-то там"" и все остальные голоса за и против любого действия.

PS. Да ни с кем я не собираюсь сраться (хотя потроллить бы не против, но это не ФКонтактик) и Петросян-mode на сайтах Stack Exchange автоматически выключается.

Comment: А после достижения порога в 200 репы в день текст должен быть "Вам пришло 10 репутации, но мы её вам не дадим, потому что у вас докУментов нету". :)

Comment: Если кроме шуток: расскажите, почему для вас важно немедленно узнавать о голосах на ваших сообщениях?

Comment: @NickVolynkin  А разве голосование это не действие? А хорошо это было бы чтобы например сразу переформулировать вопрос или ответ опираясь на реакцию сообщества. Конечно если какой-нибудь чел не злостный хейтер и просто специально минусует.

Comment: @NickVolynkin  А по 200 репы в день срывать мне не суждено — ибо я не сижу на этом сайте часами, днями и ночами.

Comment: @EugenEray если вопрос не является тихим ужасом, то обычно вместе с минусами появляются и комментарии.

Comment: @NickVolynkin хочу получать уведомления о минусах немедленно, чтобы тотчас же начать отписывать комменты "за что минусы, алё?", а если есть комменты, то начать говорить что они не правы и посраться, а еще создавать темы на мете о несправедливости и минусующих типках и о том куда глядят модераторы, что всё куда катится и надо менять власть и всё менять. хватитэтотерпеть!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Жириновский одобряет!

Comment: Реквестирую фичу уведомлений о `Модераторском произволе`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нотификации, о которых вы говорите, как я понимаю, возможны: [вот пример userscript'а](http://shu8.github.io/SE_Notifications/), который получает их, используя websocket.

Почему это не встроено в приложение? Это нужно спрашивать у авторов приложения. Думаю, что активных пользователей эти нотификации раздражают, а неактивным и не нужно.

В любом случае, API есть, так что вы как программист можете сами написать своё приложение-нотификатор.

Comment: `Думаю, что активных пользователей эти нотификации раздражают` - но ведь их можно выключить в настройках) Да и в принципе отказаться на этапе задания вопроса "хотите получать уведомления?"... Это я так, просто